# How I can get the loop result as list or string

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I write this code

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for m in range(i):
        print(i)
```

And I get the output like this:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
```

How I can get the output as an iterator (list or tuple) like this

```
1[1]
2[2,2]
or simple string like this (In each category of numbers, we return to the line) 
1
22
333
```

Comment: `for i in range(6): print(str(i + 1) * (i + 1))`

Comment: You can do it by creating one or the other (list or string) in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for iterable format output:

```py
for i in range(1,6):
    print(i, [i]*i)
```

output ->

```bash
1 [1]
2 [2, 2]
3 [3, 3, 3]
4 [4, 4, 4, 4]
5 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

or this for string format output:

```py
for i in range(1,6):
    print(str(i)*i)
```

output ->

```bash
1
22
333
4444
55555
```